# How to get a bot to save the message after a trigger word (discord.py)

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to get my bot to respond to a message sent after a trigger word, but all it does is send me the following error: `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'content'`. Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "report":
        await message.author.send("Type your report below")
        def check(m):
            return m.guild == None and m.author == message.author
        try:
            response = client.wait_for("message", check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await message.author.send("Uh-oh, the request timed out! Try again.")
        else:
            content = response.content
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) is a coroutine function. That means, in order to use it, you have to await it.

You just have to do:

```
response = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
```